# How do I cache data from a JSON API in PHP?

Tags: php, caching

In my PHP app I am retrieving data from a REST API (namely PokeAPI) and want to be able to cache the information I retrieve from it in order to cut down on time and API requests. What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Here is the code I am using the API for:

```
<?php
$base = "http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/";

if (isset($_POST["dexno"])) {
  $dexarray = $_POST["dexno"];
  foreach( $dexarray as $d ) {
    $data = @file_get_contents($base.$d);
    if ($data != "") {
      $pokemon = json_decode($data);
      $img = $pokemon->sprites->front_default;
      $imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($img));
      echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.$imageData.'">'.'<br>';
      echo $pokemon->name.'<br>';
    }  }
}
?>
```

This simply takes numerical data from an array, puts it into a URL and pulls information from the URL generated. Any help would be much appreciated, as I have only just started learning PHP.

Comment: I am not sure - give the reason why you want to cache? how long? how frequent do you pull from API? Caching have different meanings in term of Architect the applications.

Comment: If the simple file-based solutions in the answers aren't satisfactory, look at things like MemCached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
$json = ""; //your json string.

$fh = fopen("myCacheFile.jsoN" , "w+");
fwrite($fh , $json);
fclose($fh);
```

If you want short code:

```
file_put_contents("myCacheFile.json" , $json);
```

To Retrieve:

```
$arr = json_decode(file_get_contents("myCacheFile.json") , true);
```

Comment: Just to clarify, do I put this code outside of my 'foreach' section? The part where I save it to the file that is

Comment: Yes outside , otherwise you'll overkill I/O

Answer (score 0):

You can simply store the data in file on disk, and next time before making the call read from disk.

You can store it in database, and read from there.

You can use redis / memcached to store it in memory.